# Background Image appears to be "flickering" in Chrome (I don't want it to)

Tags: css, google-chrome, background, background-image

If you look at http://www.disk-edits.com.au/index.php in Chrome (vs Firefox for example),
the background appears to be shimmering/flickering/fuzzy. The image appears to move from side to side.
Whatever you want to call it, it hurts my eyes.

I want the background image to not do this. I cannot figure out why it appears this way in Chrome and not in firefox.

Here is the css:

```
body{
    background-color:#000;
    background-image:url(../images/bg.png);
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

Obviously the only relevant line is `background-image:url(../images/bg.png);`.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I can't see it in Chrome 17 on Linux.
A screenshot would be helpfull.

Comment: A screenshot didn't seem to really show it. So here is a screen capture. It also appears that it sometimes happens in firefox, like when in fullscreen mode. http://disk-edits.com.au/images/flickering-background.avi

Answer (score 2):

It's the way you exported the image. There is an option that specifies how you want the image to load whether it starts blurry then goes sharp or load from the top to the bottom.

What you have in the website is called an Interlace Effect, I think you're looking for a Serial Effect.

No matter what, I have a good connection and the image slowly loads. Your server can contribute to the problem too if it's slow.

Comment: How should I save it in Photoshop CS5? I've been experimenting a bit but can't find any options to save it with a Serial effect (or anyhting similar). None of the settings I changed seem to make much difference. I've realised that Firefox also does it when in fullscreen mode. The image appears to move from side to side. It's like the browser doesn't know where to position it and then repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a Chrome related problem, I see now flickering in many sites, on slideshows, rollover, and other elements on the page.
It is like Chrome put a white background for an istant on the element that is refreshed by some css/js...

Here a link: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102706